# Tags in Google Tag Manager is Not Firing

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

anyone can help on answering why all tags I created in GTM cannot be fired? Thanks!
[GTM_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WRNj.jpg).  [GTM_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFbUJ.jpg). [GTM_3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VlSE.jpg)

Comment: Your tags don't fire because your triggers don't fire. And the triggers don't fire because the conditions in them aren't met.

Comment: you should provide more info. Probably triggers are not set correctly